# Getting Tiehandler null error and faultcode S:Server Java SOAP Service

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-boot, java-ws

I have created a Soap service in spring-boot using the following blog 
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/07/writing-consuming-soap-webservice-spring.html

The Endpoint Publish Url

```
@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      Endpoint.p
    Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9000" +"/service/serve", new ServeWeb());

}
```

The WebService Class is as follows

```
@WebService
public class ServeWeb {

    @Autowired
    XyzService xyzService;


    @WebMethod(operationName="LOGIN")
    public List<String> userLogin(
            @WebParam(name = "uid")String uid, 
            @WebParam(name = "pwd")String pwd){ 

           System.out.println("uid == "+uid+"::::: pwd == "+pwd);
            List<String> userDetaillist =xyzService.userLogin(uid, pwd);
        return userDetaillist;
    }
}
```

I am getting following error on console

2016-11-30 00:00:24 [pool-3-thread-2] ERROR

```
c.s.x.i.ws.server.sei.TieHandler - null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.user.userLogin(ServeWeb.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:68)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:134)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:73)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:404)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:706)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:82)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using SoapUI to test here is request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://web.abhimanyu.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:LOGIN>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <uid>admin123</uid>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <pwd>admin123</pwd>
      </web:LOGIN>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the corresponding response is

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out Spring autowiring was not working. I annotated ServeWeb with @Service and it works fine after that